# IBM Worklight 6.0 - content root and local worklight server set-up

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am teaching myself Worklight. I followed the Get Started guide provided by IBM (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

Examples in the above site use relative path to link to a page or getting images. Is it possible to put a / (foreward slash) in front of each link to make it relative to the root folder? If possible, how can I configure my local worklight server so the links and images work on the app?

I have app set up as below directory structures in the /common/ directory. Many pages load shared header and menu on the page. When I use `<a href="/app-pages/page1.html">`' or `<img src="/images/ImageName.png">`, This causes 404. Not Found - `http://localhost:10080/images/ImageName.png`

- home.html
- /app-pages/page1.html
- /app-pages/page2.html
- /app-pages/sub-cat/pageA.html
- /app-pages/sub-cat/pageB.html
- /shared/header.html
- /shared/menu.html
- /images
- /css/
- /js/
- /jqueryMobile

FYI, my dev environment is as below.

1. Windows 7
2. Eclipse Juno
3. Worklight 6.0

Comment: Can you rephrase the question so that it will mention the actual problem? What are you trying to do in your app that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new Worklight application called "test", under the common folder you will have the following hierarchy:

- css
- images
- js
- test.html

In test.html, if I will add `<src="images/icon.png"/>` then once previewing the app the icon.png image located in the images folder will be displayed:

[image]

I see that you are also trying to use multiple pages in your app. Make sure to read the [Building a multi-page application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#client-basics) training module.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Yes, I did go through the multi-page apptraining. I wanted to use .loadPage() rather than just content in the first page's data-rol="content" so Device back button works. I also wanted to use only one js file that can be globally used to navigate rather than creating page specific JS files for each page. It looks like the only solution is to put all the html files in the same folder and put changePage() in the first page to move to the app-pages directory so the same relative path always work. Thanks for the comment.